# php set cookie issue

Tags: php, setcookie

I'm setting a cookie on localhost with the following syntax

```
setcookie("testCookie ", "hello cookie", false, "/", false);
```

The problem is the first time I visit the page the cookie is created and firebug shows

```
Cookie testCookie added.  hello cookie
```

But it does not read the value.  If I refresh the page, the value is read and fire bug shows

```
Cookie testCookie changed.  hello cookie
```

How can I get the value of the cookie to be read the first time the page is loaded?

Comment: What is your code to detect the cookie being either added or changed? Also to get the value of the cookie the first page load after will **NOT** show it, it will display after a second refresh.

Comment: that is my question why it doesn't show on first page load / what can i do to read the value of cookie the first time??

Comment: See my answer which should explain how it works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I put in my comment, from your description (although fairly vague and not too understandable), I think the issue may be that you're trying to read the cookie before it's sent to the server.

The way a cookie works is as follows:

1. You make a request
2. Server SENDS cookie header back to client
3. Page loads - Cookie is **NOT** visible to PHP on this page load
4. Refresh
5. Client SENDS cookie header to server
6. Server RECEIVES cookie header thus PHP can read it
7. Page loads - Cookie **IS** visible here.

If you haven't tried already, refresh again!

Since you want to read it at the same time you're setting it, just store the value you're setting and use that. Alternatively (although this is untested), you could manually set it in the `$_COOKIE` array.

So something like this:

```
setcookie("helloworld", .. );
$_COOKIE['helloworld'] = $value;
```

Then you can read it normally. Note that I wouldn't really recommend overriding the value of an automatic superglobal (same goes for `$_REQUEST`, `$_POST`, `$_GET`, etc.), and would instead suggest that you just store the value you're setting and use that.

---

Another approach would be to use a form of "gateway", meaning you'd set the cookie on a gateway page, which will then continue to redirect you to the next page.

For example, say your flow was as follows: `login.php` -> `account.php`. Rather than POST'ing your login form straight to `account.php` you have 2 options.

Opt 1: POST back to login.php, set the cookie, and then redirect to `account.php`.
Opt 2: Have a gateway, such as `logincheck.php`, POST through to that, set the cookie, and then redirect to `account.php`.

This way, `account.php` can always see your cookie.

Comment: No prob, just uploaded my answer with a better workaround though! :-)

Answer (score 3):

It may be related or not, but you are assigning boolean values to parameters that expect integers or strings. If you are new to PHP, it's very important that you read the manual carefully and understand function signatures. In this case you have to check http://php.net/setcookie where you can read this:

> bool setcookie ( string $name [,
>   string $value [, int $expire = 0 [,
>   string $path [, string $domain [, bool
>   $secure = false [, bool $httponly =
>   false ]]]]]] )

Also, I'm getting a warning when I run your code:

```
Warning: Cookie names cannot contain any of the following '=,; \t\r\n\013\014'
```

Comment: tnx for the reply, initially i was unable to set the cookie on localhost so searching yielded this code :) i'll fix it later...