# Submit buttons needing to be pressed twice to load page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, cookies

I've created a dual language website with a form that when submitted saves a cookie, each page then checks the cookie to see what language to load.

The problem I'm having is that the submit buttons need to be pressed twice for it to load the page and switch the language.

This is the form I have:

```
<form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" name="region" method="post">
   <input type="submit" name="region" value="English" id="en-button" />
   <input type="submit" name="region" value="Cymraeg" id="cy-button" />
</form>
```

This is in my functions.php file to save the cookie:

```
function set_region_cookie()
{
    if(isset($_POST['region']))
    {
        // Set Cookie
        setcookie('region', $_POST['region'], time()+1209600);
        // Reload the current page so that the cookie is sent with the request
        header('Region: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    }
}
add_action('init', 'set_region_cookie');
```

And this is what I have around each content area to load the different content:

```
<?php $language = $_COOKIE["region"];
if ($language == "English") { ?>
    <?php echo the_field('english_content'); ?>
<?php } else { ?>
    <?php echo the_field('welsh_content'); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

The language switches correctly but only when you click the submit buttons twice.

Comment: So you're saying that the first time one of the `submit` buttons is clicked, the form is **not** submitted? If so, what browser are you using, does it happen across all browsers?

Comment: @deifwud When I click the submit button the page reloads, then when I click it again the page reloads but this time the language actually changes. So to make the language change I need to click it twice. I'm using Chrome but it happens in Safari & Firefox.

Comment: okay - so the form is actually submitting - are you calling `set_region_cookie` **before** assigning `$language = $_COOKIE['region']`?

Comment: @deifwud I'm not really sure! `set_region_cookie` is in my functions.php file with the form in my header.php file.

Comment: I don't know a great deal about Wordpress setups so I can't help you much there unfortunately, try and find out where, and at which point the `set_region_cookie()` function gets called. It sounds like you're trying to assign `$language = $_COOKIE['region']` before setting the cookie, which would explain why it only starts to work after submitting the form for the second time

Comment: @deifwud Hmm, the only way I can be sure is to somehow get my function out of the functions.php file and into my template!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that the problem arises as a result of the way that cookies work, found the following (vital) information [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936054/php-set-cookie-issue):

> The way a cookie works is as follows:
>
> 1. You make a request
> 2. Server SENDS cookie header back to client
> 3. Page loads - Cookie is NOT visible to PHP on this page load
> 4. Refresh
> 5. Client SENDS cookie header to server
> 6. Server RECEIVES cookie header thus PHP can read it
> 7. Page loads - Cookie IS visible here.

I never actually noticed at first, but there is actually a line of code in the question to deal with refreshing the page so that the server receives the cookie:-

```
// Reload the current page so that the cookie is sent with the request
header('Region: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Change that to:

```
// Reload the current page so that the cookie is sent with the request
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Comment: I'll award the bounty as soon as it'll let me!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a select field instead. The browser might just be freaking out because there is two submit buttons. Then you can do something like `document.getElementById('theSelectMenu').onchange = function(){ document.getElementById('theForm').submit(); }` or better yet use jQuery for it.

Comment: I don't really have the option to put it in dropdowns as this was how it was designed.